# Get Value of visibility of series

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to get the value of the visibility of a series? I know how to change it. But is there anything like series.getVisibility()?

Answer (score 9):

There's a read-only property on the [`series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Series) object named `visible` that you can use for that.

```
series.visible
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `chart` is your chart var.
`chart.series[0].visible`, gets the first serie visibility.